# How to prove A and B are independent if P(A) = 0 or P(A)=1?

Tags: probability

How to prove A and B are independent if P(A) = 0 or P(A)=1?

I understand that independence is when $P(A \bigcap B)=P(A)*P(B) $

So I took the case where P(A) = 0

Then we have  $P(A \bigcap B)=0$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: for any number $x\in[0,1]$, $0\times x=0$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Ah, got it, thanks! P(A)*P(B) = 0

Comment: @ArnaudMortier But is that the correct proof? Can I start with P(A⋂B)=P(A)∗P(B)?

Comment: Where to go from there: Just insert into the independence equation to get $0=0\times P(B)$. When does that equation hold?

Comment: @celtschk Can I start with the independence equation for the proof?

Comment: For the proof you must *prove* the equation.

Comment: You already started with $P(A)=0$. By inserting into the independence equation you get a condition when it holds. Which is exactly what you need here.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla How to do that? Do I need to do that for this question?

Comment: When you wrote $P(A\cap B)=0$ I assumed that you had understood how to prove that **without using the equation that you want to prove (obviously)**.
Use the fact that $A\cap B\subset A$ and $P(A)=0$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I just want to prove A and B are independent if P(A) = 0 or P(A)=1. Does that require me to prove  P(A⋂B)=P(A)∗P(B)?

Comment: @Programmer: Indeed, you have to prove it. Because that equation **is** the statement that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @celtschk I'm so confused how to do that.

Comment: Start with $P(A)=0$ (as you did). Then prove that $P(A\cap B)=0$ *without* using the independence equation. Then insert both into the independence equation and see that it holds.

Comment: @celtschk How to prove  P(A∩B)=0?

Comment: See the hint by @ArnaudMortier

Comment: @celtschk I got that, but still extremely confused about what I'm trying to do

Comment: Since I don't know where your confusion lies, I don't know how to help you with it. For my eyes, the whole way to the solution (for $P(A)=0$) is sketched in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74936/discussion-between-programmer-and-celtschk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P(A)=0$ then by monotonicity
$$
 0 \leq P(A\cap B) \leq P(A) = 0
$$
so
$$
P(A\cap B) = 0 = P(A) = P(A)\cdot P(B)
$$
This shows that if $P(A)=0$ the $A$ and $B$ are independent.

If $P(A)=1$, let $A^\complement$ denotes the complement of $A$. First note that
$$
P(A^\complement) = 1-P(A) = 0
$$
and by monotonicity we see that $P(A^\complement \cap B) = 0$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
P(A\cap B) = P(A\cap B) + P(A^\complement \cap B)
&=P([A\cap B]\cup [A^\complement \cap B])\\
&=P([A\cup A^\complement]\cap B)\\ 
&= P(B)\\
&=P(B)\cdot P(A)
\end{align*}
where the last line holds since $P(A)=1$. So once again we have $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ which shows that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @Programmer Does this clarify the problem?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

For the case $P(A) = 1$: $A$ isn't all the space, but "almost":
$$
P(A\cap B) = P(A\cap B) + 0 = P(A\cap B) + P((X\setminus A)\cap B)) = P(B) = \cdots.
$$
*Why* $P((X\setminus A)\cap B)) = 0$?